# MYSQL HAVING and WHERE with condition

Tags: mysql

I have a user_table with columns

- first_name
- last_name
- contact_number

For a autocomplete UI, user is free to search anything.

I want to allow user to search by full_name as well as contact_number with like query.

Query I have written is like,

```
select CONCAT(u.first_name ,' ', u.last_name) as full_name, contact_number from user_table u where contact_number like '%value%' HAVING full_name like '%value%';
```

It is not working as value will be same for contact_number and full_name both. If I remove either contact_number or Having close then partially it is working for either case. I am not able to put OR clause between where and having.

Comment: `HAVING` should only be used in combination with `GROUP BY`

Comment: Why did you think HAVING would be useful here I wonder.

Comment: If I put full_name in where clause, then MySQL gives error like "Unknown column 'full_name' in 'where clause' "

Comment: Yuou just need an `or`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the post

> I want to allow user to search by full_name as well as contact_number with like query.

You can use `OR` operator in the `WHERE` clause as below, if you want to search with `contact_number` and `full_name`

```
 select CONCAT(u.first_name ,' ', u.last_name) as full_name 
 from user_table u 
 where contact_number like '%value%' 
       OR CONCAT(u.first_name ,' ', u.last_name) like '%value%';
```

or

```
 select CONCAT(u.first_name ,' ', u.last_name) as full_name 
 from user_table u 
 where contact_number like '%value%' 
       OR u.first_name like '%value%'
       OR u.last_name like '%value%';
```

Comment: But full_name is not inside table metadata. It is generated using CONCAT.

Comment: @Nimesh In this case you can use the `CONCAT(u.first_name ,' ', u.last_name)` instead of `full_name`. Please check the updated answer

Comment: No it will not work because in my free form textbox value may be mixture of first_name and last_name

Comment: @Nimesh Can you please add some sample data, input parameter and the expected output. It will helpful to understand the exact scenario.

Comment: I got a solution with "select CONCAT(p.first_name ,' ', p.last_name) as full_name, contact_number from user_table p HAVING full_name like '%Nimesh S%' or contact_number like '%888%'; " but I don't know is it ideal solution or not but it is working.

Comment: @Nimesh If you got an answer, you can add your own as answer and accept yours.

Comment: @Nimesh `HAVING` is applied after aggregation, `WHERE` is applied before aggregation. You don't have aggregation. Use `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONCAT(p.first_name ,' ', p.last_name) as full_name, contact_number from user_table p HAVING full_name like '%Nimesh S%' or contact_number like '%Nimesh S%';
```

or

```
select CONCAT(p.first_name ,' ', p.last_name) as full_name, contact_number from user_table p HAVING full_name like '%888%' or contact_number like '%888%';
```

or [Generalised Query]

```
select CONCAT(p.first_name ,' ', p.last_name) as full_name, contact_number from user_table p HAVING full_name like '%value%' or contact_number like '%value%';
```

Comment: Please describe those lines of code, what they do, why you suggest them,...

Comment: @DanFromGermany, I want to query table like, any of the column matches the value that I pass to query. But in UI, there is only one textbox and a user can write either name, contact number or nay detail and he should be able to get result. So the input to the query will be only one value and query should try to find any column that contains value passed from textbox. Now the table has first name and last name column separate but for end user it is full name which is not available in table. To search on aggregate column, I used Having but Having and where both can't be used in single query.